# How good scapy is in replaying a pcap file?

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp, wireshark, scapy

I am trying to measure the packet leaving and reaching time via scapy. Is it possible to measure the time when packet leaves the node? If so, How good scapy is in replaying exact those timestamps? Plus how to verify its credibility. Is it possible to compare scapy timestamps with wireshark's? If so then how?

I know these are lots of questions. but I really need these answers. I thank in advance for your patience and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Scapy is **not** really good at replaying a PCAP file (if you want to be fast, I mean).

If you need better performances than what Scapy can offer, you should probably use `tcpreplay`; you can do that directly from Scapy, using the `sendpfast()` function.